How to overwrite @TimedAspect from micrometer.core for WebFlux
TimedAspect catches errors by try/catch that doesn't work in Mono/Flux world. (success calls are okey)
Or how i can fix, for catching errors in WebFlux + GraphQl with my own attributes in metrics (for example in GRaphQL Resolver)
i try to override TimedAspect in Mono/Flux but it was badly in my case and check histogram that doesnt show anything under graphQl (only 2 endpoints /metrics, /graphQl)

Project reactor has Micrometer support, please check the .tap operator for reactor publishers, it does the same.
Please, do not cross-post: https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/5410
